# importing from a text file and make a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, text-parsing, cell-array

I have a text file that contains genes information like is a relations and part of relations between genes.

this text file contains paragraphs for each GOTerm (the GO term is a node which contains certain code number like: GO:0030436) which has: Go term ID ( the first line of each paragraph) and isa (if any)(starts with isa and end with end of isa) and partof Go Terms (if any)(starts with partof: and end with end of partof) a small sample from this text file is:

```
GO:0030436
isa:
GO:0034297
GO:0043936
GO:0048315
end of isa
partof:
GO:0042243
end of partof
genes:
end of genes
GO:0034297
isa:
end of isa
partof:
end of partof
genes:
end of genes
GO:0043936
isa:
GO:0001410
GO:0034300
GO:0034301
GO:0034302
GO:0034303
GO:0034304
end of isa
partof:
end of partof
genes:
end of genes
```

I need to read this text file and take the three data from it and make a cell matrix which has 3 columns as follows:

```
map=

ID GoTerms               is_a            partof
GO:0030436              GO:0034297       GO:0042243
GO:0030436              GO:0043936              0
GO:0030436              GO:0048315              0
GO:0034297                   0                  0
GO:0043936              GO:0001410              0
GO:0043936              GO:0034300              0
GO:0043936              GO:0034301              0
GO:0043936              GO:0034302              0
GO:0043936              GO:0034303              0
GO:0043936              GO:0034304              0
```

note that if each Go term contains more than one is a or part of terms, I should repeat the Go term ID in order to make the cell matrix fit and well-organized.

any idea about how to make this code?

I tried to make a code but it doesn't work because I don't know how to take more than 1 isa and part of terms:

```
s={};
        fid = fopen('Opt.pad'); % read from the certain text file 
        tline = fgetl(fid); 
        while ischar(tline) 
           s=[s;tline]; 
           tline = fgetl(fid); 
        end 
% find start and end positions of every [Term] marker in s 
    terms = [find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(s, '\GO:\w*'))); numel(s)+1];
      % for every [Term] section, run the previously implemented regexps
      % and save the results into a map - a cell array with 3 columns      map = cell(0,3);
      for term=1:numel(terms)-1
          % extract single [Term]  data
          s_term = s(terms(term):terms(term+1)-1);          % match regexps
          %To generate the GO_Terms vector from the text file
          tok = regexp(s_term, '^(GO:\w*)', 'tokens');
          idx = ~cellfun('isempty', tok); 
          GO_Terms=cellfun(@(x)x{1}, (tok(idx)));          %To generate the is_a relations vector from the text file
          tok = regexp(s_term, '^isa: (GO:\w*)', 'tokens'); 
          idx = ~cellfun('isempty', tok); 
          is_a_relations  =cellfun(@(x)x{1}, (tok(idx)));          %To generate the part_of relaions vector from the text file
          tok = regexp(s_term, '^partof: (GO:\w*)', 'tokens'); 
          idx = ~cellfun('isempty', tok); 
          part_of_relations =cellfun(@(x)x{1}, (tok(idx)));          % map. note the end+1 - here we create a new map row. Only once!
          map{end+1,1} = GO_Terms;
          map{end,  2} = is_a_relations;
          map{end,  3} = part_of_relations;
      end      map( cellfun(@isempty, map) ) = {0};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short and simple solution (albeit perhaps not the fastest):

```
% # Parse text file
C = textread('Opt.pad', '%s', 'delimiter', '');

% # Obtain indices for isa elements
idx = reshape(find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(C, 'isa')))', 2, []);
isa = arrayfun(@(x, y)x + 1:y - 1, idx(1, :), idx(2, :), 'Uniform', false);

% # Obtain indices for partof elements
idx = reshape(find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(C, 'partof')))', 2, []);
partof = arrayfun(@(x, y)x + 1:y - 1, idx(1, :), idx(2, :), 'Uniform', false);

% # Obtain indices of GO term elements and IDs
go = find(cellfun(@(s)any(strfind(s, 'GO:')), C));
id = go(~ismember(go, [isa{:}, partof{:}]));

% # Construct a new cell array
N = cellfun(@(x, y)max([numel(x), numel(y), 1]), isa, partof);
k = cumsum([1, N(1:end - 1)]);
X = cell(sum(N), 3); % # Preallocate memory!
repcell = @(x, n)arrayfun(@(y)x, 1:n, 'Uniform', false);
for ii = 1:numel(id)
    idx = k(ii):k(ii) + N(ii) - 1;
    X(idx, 1) = repcell(C{id(ii)}, N(ii));
    X(idx, 2) = [C{isa{ii}}, repcell('0', N(ii) - numel(isa{ii}))];
    X(idx, 3) = [C{partof{ii}}, repcell('0', N(ii) - numel(partof{ii}))];
end
```

This should yield the following output:

```
X = 

    'GO:0030436'    'GO:0034297'    'GO:0042243'
    'GO:0030436'    'GO:0043936'    '0'         
    'GO:0030436'    'GO:0048315'    '0'         
    'GO:0034297'    '0'             '0'         
    'GO:0043936'    'GO:0001410'    '0'         
    'GO:0043936'    'GO:0034300'    '0'         
    'GO:0043936'    'GO:0034301'    '0'         
    'GO:0043936'    'GO:0034302'    '0'         
    'GO:0043936'    'GO:0034303'    '0'         
    'GO:0043936'    'GO:0034304'    '0'
```

Comment: EDIT: revised the construction of the output cell array.